# Google Tag manager, Facebook Pixel pagespeed issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-tag-manager, pagespeed, facebook-pixel

We are using Next.js, and pagespeed score got worse after gtm and fb pixel, google script for sign.

for GTM, tried

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module initializing in _app.js

- importing the module on page level and initialize after component mount
- importing the module and initialized after component mount.

also tried using script tag in _app.js

```
<script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
                (function(w,d,s,l,i)
                {w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID}');
              `,
            }}
          />
```

For Facebook Pixel:
tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-pixel

- Initializing in _app.js and calling pageview on router change
  tried using script tag also,

```
 <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
                !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
                {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
                n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
                if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
                n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
                t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
                'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
                fbq('init', ${FB_PIXEL_ID});
              `,
            }}
          />
```

tried adding defer also no effect.

without tags getting score around 60,
[image: Pagespeed score without gtm and fb pixel]

with gtm and fb pixels
[image: Pagespeed score with gtm and fb pixel and google script]
[image: Pagespeed score with gtm and fb pixel and google script]

Answer (score 3):

It's hilarious that Google and Facebook recommend that we put their inline, blocking code in the head or as the first item in the body so they can start gathering data for themselves, but then Google dings us for blocking. If you want to defer these, there are two primary ways:

1. Next has a new [`Script` component to help load/lazy load/defer external scripts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script).
2. You can create a [custom `Document` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) and put your external scripts after the `NextScript` component, before the closing `</body>` tag.

These solutions would move those codes to later in the loading process so they're non-blocking, which should help with your loading times. The tradeoff is that they won't initialize until after the page is loaded, so you'd have to decide which is more important - faster loading time and better user experience for your customers, or a smidge of more analytics on users who leave the site before it fully loads at the expense of a little longer loading time.